# Code-first Entity Framework may to many relation with additional fields not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I have 3 classes that must be in a many-to-many relationship, but when I run my project, Entity Framework can't map them to SQL Server tables. I used migrations.

My user class is here:

```
 [Table("tbl_User")]
    public class User
    {
                public User()
                {
                }

                #region Properties
                [Key]
                [Required][DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]               
                public long Id { get; set; }                
                public string FirstName { get; set; }               
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string LoginName { get; set; }
                public string Email { get; set; }
                public string Password { get; set; }
                public bool EmailVerify { get; set; }
                public string Image { get; set; }               
                public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
                public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
                public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
                public bool Enabled { get; set; }
                public bool Deleted { get; set; }
                #endregion

                #region Relations               
                public virtual IList<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }          
                #endregion Relations 
    }
```

Role class is here:

```
[Table("tbl_Role")]
public class Role
{
        public Role()
        {
        }

        #region Properties
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]      
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }                
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }           
        public bool Enable { get; set; }    
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        #endregion Properties

        #region Relations                       
        public virtual IList<UserRole> UserRole { get;set;}


        #endregion Relations
}
```

`UserRole` is my many-to-many relationship table:

```
[Table("tbl_UserRole")]
public class UserRole
{
            internal class Configuration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
            {
                public Configuration()
                {
                    HasRequired(current => current.User)
                         .WithMany(userrole => userrole.UserRole)
                         .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.UserId);

                    HasRequired(current => current.Role)
                         .WithMany(userrole => userrole.UserRole)
                         .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.RoleId);
                }
            }

            public UserRole()
            {
            }

            #region Properties
            [Key]
            [Required]               
            public long Id { get; set; }        
            public DateTime GrantDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            public bool Deleted { get; set; }
            #endregion Properties

            #region Relations
            public long UserId { get; set; }
            public virtual User User { get; set; }
            public int RoleId { get; set; }
            public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
            #endregion Relations
}
```

and here is my database context

```
 public class LiveMiracleDbContext:DbContext
    {
            public LiveMiracleDbContext() : base("LMConnection")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<User> tbl_User { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Role> tbl_Role { get; set; }
            public DbSet<UserRole> tbl_UserRole { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run my project without these classes, my database is generated, but when I use these classes, my database is not generated.

Comment: Try "Update-Database -Script" to see the SQL generated by EF. Then use that to further track down your problem.

Comment: What are these `TypeConverter` attributes supposed to do? By the way, it may be a good idea to prune this forest of attributes a bit for readability.

Comment: thank u its good idea i pruned attributes for readability

Comment: tanks alot problem wass in attributes. after i removed them my database is generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok tanks for  Gert Arnold comment

problem was in my Attributes this stracture is true

i removed attributes.